# Problem with remoting react-bootstrap component: dispatcher is null

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

I am facing a strange issue in trying to remote a simple react-bootstrap component. I am tweaking the tutorial on react microfrontends found [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/micro-frontends-step-by-step-using-react-webpack-5-and-module-federation-e4b9d840ec71).

Essentially the tutorial remotes a button:

```
 <button>MFE1 Button</button>
```

and I am just adding a Col component:

```
 <div>
  <button>MFE1 Button</button>
         <Col >
          <span>First col</span>
         </Col>
  </div>
```

The remote component fails to load in the host and a "dispatcher is null" error shows in console. So also a warning that says 'invalid hook call" etc.
See [here](https://justpaste.it/8y3sj)

i am using

```
 "react":"^18.2.0",                                                
 "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4", 
 "webpack": "^5.76.1",
```

When I run locally the component displays correctly so the problem is with remoting
It also remotes correctly when the Col component is removed.

Am i missing something?

tia
nan

Answer (score 0):

Ok this turned out to be problem related to sharing modules;

The tutorial did not use shared modules so I had left it at that. It appears that react-bootstrap pulls in another copy of react and corrupts its state. (I am guessing).
The problem went away when I started using shared modules of react and react-dom. I will file a bug since at the least the error reporting can be a lot better.

Comment: If you file a bug, please also add that to this question in case people come across this same issue and that is later resolved either here or there (where the bud is raised)